# Converting Set to Array?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsset

When retrieving a collection of objects from CoreData via a relationship, swift is giving me an NSSet rather than an array as i would have expected.

Is there a way i can convert the set into an array?

Code:

```
var updateExercise : UserExercise?

destinationViewController?.userExerciseSets = self.updateExercise?.exercisesets as? [UserExerciseSet]
```

the cautions are

> Cast from 'NSSet?' to unrelated type '[UserExerciseSet]' always fails

Destination VC has the var : `var userExerciseSets : [UserExerciseSet]?`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should define your NSManagedObject model as such:

```
class UserExercise: NSManagedObject {
   @NSManaged var exercises: Set<Exercise>!
}
```

Then when you need an array, you can simply use the Array's constructor that takes a set.

```
let exercises = Array(userExercise.exercises)
```

Comment: Indeed, but remember that it's a set for a reason - *there is no guarantee of order*, and two calls to `Array()` with the same `Set` may not return elements ordered the same way...

Comment: Correct, there should also be an explicit sort in addition to this if it's used for display in the UI.  Good catch.